# Validate rich:dataTable value size's on form submit

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a "new item" form that requires a list of dates, with the following components:

- A `<rich:calendar>` input;
- A `<a4j:commandButton>` that adds the chosen date to a `List<Date> chosenDates` in the backing bean;
- A `<rich:dataTable>` with it's `value` set to the `List<Date> chosenDates` attribute;
- A `<a4j:commandButton>` per dataTable row that removes it's date from the`List<Date> chosenDates`;

How to **validate** (JSF's validation phase) the size of the `chosenDates` list on form submit (creation process)?

RichFaces 4, JSF 2.1 (Mojarra).

Comment: You can get the the size of the tableModel/List of what is populating your rich:dataTable. You can do that on the facelet/view.

Comment: I'm sorry I changed the word "validate" for "check". Edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise a cleaner approach with a JSF PhaseListener. The JSF processing will stop skip ahead the other phases if validation fails. Create a [`PhaseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) that will inspect the size of your list *during* the validations phase as against during the model update/invoke action phase. Try something like this

1. Create a phase listener for the validations phase

   ```
   public class TestPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

      @Override
      public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }

      @Override
      public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {

         if(event.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS)){
           FacesContext ctx = event.getFacesContext();
           YourBeanClass theBeanClass = ctx.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(ctx, "#{someBean}", YourNeanClass.class); //obtain a reference to the backing bean containing the list
   /*
      inspect the size of the list here and based on that throw the exception below
    */
          throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Too many dates","Too Many Dates"));
         }
      }

       @Override
       public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
       }
    }
   ```
2. Register your new listener in the `faces_config.xml` file

   ```
   <lifecycle>
      <phase-listener>your.package.structure.TestPhaseListener</phase-listener>
   </lifecycle>
   ```

EDIT: Based on your comment, as an alternative, you can hook into the component's lifecycle using the `<f:event/>` tag and the `preValidate` or `postValidate` events (depending on your preference)

1. A listener tag to your component

   ```
      <rich:dataTable>
          <f:event type="preValidate" listener="#{yourBean.listener}"/>
      </rich:dataTable>
   ```
2. Define a listener method in your backing bean to run per your defined event. The method signature **must** take an argument of type `ComponentSystemEvent`

   ```
       public void preCheck(ComponentSystemEvent evt){
          //You're in your backing bean so you can do pretty much whatever you want. I'd advise you mark the request as validation failed and queue FacesMessages. Obtain a reference to FacesContext and:

           facesContext.validationFailed();


        }
   ```

Comment: Yeah I considered doing this, but I still don't want to mess with the lifecycle. This class will run every form submit or navigation case. I'm looking for a solution using JSF tags like `<f:validate>` or such. If there's another way to implement a "list adding" that can be validated, I will consider too.

Comment: @kauedg, added an alternative based on tags

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:
`#{yourBean.chosenDates.size()}`
I suppose you have a getter called getChosenDates which returns the chosenDates list.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your "validation concerns":

You can create a `Validate` method in your bean and return list of `ValidationMessages`. A sample is below, one that i used in my code.

```
public List<ValidationMessage> validate() {
    List<ValidationMessage> validations = new ArrayList<ValidationMessage>();
    int curSampleSize = sampleTable.getDataModel().getRowCount();

    if(getNumberOfSamples() != null) {
        size += getNumberOfSamples();
    } else {
        validations.add(new ValidationMessage("Please enter the no of samples to continue."));
        return validations;
    }           

    return validations;
}
```

Then, on submit you can check if you have any `ValidationMessages` as follows:

```
List<ValidationMessage> errs = validate();

if(errs.size()>0) {
    FacesValidationUtil.addFacesMessages(errs);
    return null;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have no problem using validation/converters, as the other inputs are correctly validated, by means of the attribute `validator=#{xxxValidator.validate}"`. My problem is that the `<rich:dataTable>` does not have such attribute to bind to a validator class, so I need a tag that will be bound to a validator, to check if the `List<Date> chosenDate` is not empty on form submit (before the actual `save()` method executes). Hope I've been clear now.

Comment: What about binding it to a JavaScript event like onSubmit or onClick. You can return a boolean true or false if the #{not empty myBean.chosenDate} i.e. if it is not empty return true else - false. You can do that with JavaScript on clicking on your submit button (commandButton)

Comment: And by the way the validation i explained above will result in NOT submitting the form if the size is zero. So, effectively you can use validation to halt form submission.

Comment: I avoid using JavaScript pieces of code at all. I already have the object's validator I just need to link a validator tag in the view to the validator class. If there's really no other way, then I'll use the suggestion. Thanks!